# Azure function. 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.34.0'

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nuget-package, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to run an Azure Function v4 from Visual Studio, I know the function is correct because it works correctly in other computers from the same repo. I already removed and Clone the solution but still it won't work, the error is:
"*A host error has occurred during startup operation
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs,Version=3.0.34.0*"

I noticed that the exception says that I'm using version 3.0.34.0 from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs although I installed the Version 3.0.37 using Nuget Manager

[image]

also the reference in the .csproj indicates it is 3.0.37

[image]

I already cleaned, rebuild, eliminated the bin and obj folders and it keeps showing the same error

[image]

I also looked for any "3.0.34.0" version of anything but couldn't find any, not sure why it says that version is being used, I even tried to downgrade to that version but it is the only one that doesn't exists and that was really frustrating

[image]

Please, help me

Comment: Please share the code in text format instead of images.

Comment: Please share the code snippet of the `DefaultExtensionRegistryFactory.cs` file.

Answer (score 1):

Removing and reinstalling all "Microsoft.Azure" packages has fixed the issue.

Comment: Same exact problem here and removing and reinstalling Microsoft.Azure packages didn't work for me. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue and this is what helped me. I removed all the NuGet References. Mainly Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus

Then I have reinstalled two NuGet References.

1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus (same as above)
2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (this is additional)

A key things, I noticed here is, I am having both the same major version and that works.
For me, its

1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus (5.13.4)
2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (5.0.0)

In case if this helps anyone...

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the nuget cache.

`nuget locals all -clear`